# Passing GET variables into PHP to instantiate classes and call functions

Tags: php, html, function, variables, get

I successfully instantiated the object class but I can't figure out how to call a function.
Here is my PHP code:

```
$obj = new router();
class router{

public function __construct(){
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
        echo "GET";
        $page = 'index';
        $funct = 'myfuncempty';

        if (!empty ($_GET)){
            $page = $_GET['page'];
            $funct = $_GET['func'];
        }
        $obj = new $page(); //instantiating object with get from class
        $obj->funct;
    }
    else{
        echo "POST";
    }

}

}
class index{

public function __construct(){
    echo "hello I'm index";
}
public function myfunc(){
    echo "yo";
}

public function myfuncempty(){
    echo "empty get";
}
}

class login{
public function __construct(){
    echo "hello I'm login";
}

public function loggedin(){
    echo "you're logged in";
}

public function loggedinempty(){
    echo "its empty";
}
}
```

And this is the HTML form that I use to pass variables via GET:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="POST"><input type ="text" name="page" id="page" /><input type="submit" /></form>
<form action="index.php" method="GET">Page:<input type="text" name="page" id="page" />Function:<input type="text" name="func" id="func" /><input type= "submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I type index in for page and myfunc in for function, I get this response:

```
GEThello I'm login Notice: Undefined property: login::$funct in /home/cr47/public_html/final_project/index.php on line 27
```

So, it is passing the 'page' correctly and instantiating the object but it is not correctly calling the myfunc function.
Any ideas?

Comment: @ThiefMaster What, are hackers going to hack into the machine, create their own compromised class and instantiate it with a $_GET parameter?

Comment: Chances are good there are classes in his application or builtin PHP classes which are not "safe" when someone can call arbitrary methods on them. Even though the risk is just moderate without being able to pass any arguments. But anyway, you can at least cause errors which might then spam into a logfile or trigger emails to somebody.

Comment: Having changed my mind over this myself, I sternly disagree with you on principle. But voting your solution up for correct answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$obj->funct;` with `$obj->$funct();`

But **be careful**. You shouldn't let your users instantiate arbitrary classes. At least use a whitelist or require them to be a subclass of some custom class only used by your classes which are safe (i.e. no public methods that do anything a user shouldn't be able to do).

Comment: Thanks!  It worked.  :)  I would never do something like this on an actual site.  It's just a homework assignment I've been stuck on all weekend.  I figured it was just some syntax I wasn't getting.